# Why does it say in runtime that my json field is empty?

Tags: json, delphi, request

I have a json field: recurringindicator and it's value has to be 'true'.
So I am building my json like this:

```
Writer.WriteStartObject;
Writer.WritePropertyName('access');
Writer.WriteStartObject;
Writer.WritePropertyName('balances');
Writer.WriteStartArray;
Writer.WriteEndArray;
Writer.WritePropertyName('transactions');
Writer.WriteStartArray;
Writer.WriteEndArray;
Writer.WriteEndObject;
Writer.WritePropertyName('recurringIndicator');
Writer.WriteValue(true);
Writer.WritePropertyName('validuntil');
Writer.WriteValue('2021-12-31');
Writer.WritePropertyName('frequencyPerDay');
Writer.WriteValue('4');
Writer.WriteEndObject;
Showmessage(StringBuilder.ToString);
```

which builds the json string:

```
{"access":{"balances":[],"transactions":[]},
"recurringIndicator":true,
"validUntil":"2021-12-31",
"frequencyPerDay":"4"}
```

but in runtime I get that the "recurringIndicator" field is empty.
Can somebody please help me with this?

```
Restrequest2.AddBody(StringBuilder);
Restrequest2.Execute;
```

Answer (score 3):

In this call

```
Restrequest2.AddBody(StringBuilder);
```

you are serializing the *StringBuilder* instance instead of the string content.

This should work:

```
Restrequest2.AddBody(StringBuilder.ToString, TRESTContentType.ctAPPLICATION_JSON);
```

Comment: Yeah it is working ! Thank you very much sir Uwe Raabe, i understood now